# Set UINavigationController Title when presenting UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a `SwiftUI` view which is pushed to `UINavigationController` stack. I don't have any `NavigationView` inside SwiftUI and I want to show title text. How can I achieve this?

How can I create my controller:

```
let viewModel = SettingsViewModel()
let settingsView = SettingsView().environmentObject(viewModel)
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: settingsView)
controller.title = "Settings"
return UIHostingController(rootView: settingsView)
```

What is inside SwiftUI

```
struct SettingsView: View {

// MARK: - Properties
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: SettingsViewModel

// MARK: - View
var body: some View {
    List(viewModel.settingItems) { item in
        Text(item.rawValue)
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Doesn't `controller.title` work for you?

Comment: No didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You returning `settingsView` as rootviewcontroller which has `viewModel` as a object but its empty like you declared to first `let viewModel = SettingsViewModel()` So below List has zero item.

```
var body: some View {
List(viewModel.settingItems) { item in
    Text(item.rawValue)
 }
}
```

On the other hand , you declare `controller` but it never used

```
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: settingsView)
controller.title = "Settings"
```

> I have a really smaller information about swiftUI but your problem must be one of these